# I am using CollabNetSubversionEdge to connect svn

Tags: svn

I am using below command to connect with SVN :

```
svn export http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/ABC/Axure/Tortoies "C:\yna\svn"
```

but I want to pass USERID and PASSWORD along with this command.

Answer (score 0):

Global options `--username` and `--password` applicable in all commands there|if authorization if needed

Read `svn help export`